# Send output file from for loop to a new directory in R

Tags: r, for-loop, directory

I have used a for loop to load some files, perform some tasks and write the results to a new csv file. The directory where the input files are stored was set before running the loop, but rather than saving the output csv file to the same directory, I would like to send it to a new directory within the loop.

Here is a very simple for loop example:

```
p <- "~/Desktop/MyFolder"
setwd(p)

files <- list.files(path=dir, pattern="csv$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(files)){

  f <- lapply(files[i], read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  cat2 <- f[f$mod ==2, c(1,6)]
  filename <- files[1]
  tn <- strsplit(filename,"_")[[1]][1] 
  fn <- paste(tn, "_trimmed.csv", sep="")
  write.csv(cat2, file=fn, row.names=FALSE)

}
```

I am quite new to R and have not been able to find out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I think I don't understand your question. If you now the new directory you want to save the file just add it to write.csv function, you can use paste("/newdir", "output.csv", sep=""), is that what you want?

Comment: Or you can use the `file.path()` function to generate a path that's independent of your operating system's folder separator: `file.path("newdir", "output.csv")`

Comment: another problem you're going to have is that you never change the name of the output file, so you're going to over write you data in each loop.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions! Really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So assuming that the folders don't already exist, and you want to create them and then put output.csv in each, the following should work:

```
p <- "~/Desktop/MyFolder"
setwd(p)

files <- list.files(path=dir, pattern="csv$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(files)){

  f <- lapply(files[i], read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  #why not:
  #f <- read.csv(files[i],header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  cat2 <- f[f$mod ==2, c(1,6)] 
  dir.create(paste0("folder",i), showWarnings = FALSE) #stops warnings if folder already exists
  write.csv(cat2, file.path(paste0("folder",i), "output.csv"), row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Your `lapply()` statement looks unnecessary to me, but maybe there's something that I'm missing

Comment: @ Miff: Thanks for the answer. This is very helpful. As rrs points out my for loop currently writes over each file so I have updated my question to include code that will name each output file according to the input file name.It is easy enough to substitute the code in your answer! How would you get this to work if you wanted to save the new folder in a directory other than the working one? Thanks!

Comment: @ Miff: Just realised that sebkoft has already answered my question! Thanks!